# JPEG size made smaller by MSPAINT, why?

Tags: jpeg

I have lots of JPEGs from DSLR, and they are roughly about 5-6MB per JPEG. I open any of them using MSPAINT, and click the SAVE and notice the size immediately go down to 2-3MB.

Why? Is Mspaint doing a lossy or lossless compression?

Comment: JPEG is by definition lossy compression format.

Comment: How can one not know that JPEG is a lossy format and you can specify the "quality"?

Comment: I know JPEG is lossy. but like the command jpegoptim, which can do the 'lossless' compression on JPEG by removing the exif....  In mspaint, there is no setting for this quality, and I am just pressing the Ctrl+S

Comment: EXIF is meta-data, it has nothing to do with image quality. There is no lossless mode in JPEG. Please, read up on JPEG: what it is, and how it works. But this very off-topic for SO anyways as it's not programming related.

Comment: I know it is off topic, so where should I post this question to?

Comment: [SuperUser](http://superuser.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things Paint May be doing:

1. Using different quantization tables
2. Subsampling the Cb and Cr color components
3. Using optimal huffman tables.
4. Stripping out metadata.

You an run a JPEG dumping program on the two versions and compare the output to see the changes